# nginx config for nodejs api not returning /api calls

Tags: json, node.js, rest, nginx, command-line-interface

Having trouble configuring NGINX to serve JSON from nodejs.  Static files are serving fine, but the /API requests are timing out.

**NGINX config file**

```
server {
    listen 80;  
    root /home/doctorep/doctoreports;
    #index index.html index.htm;

    server_name doctoreports.com;

    location / {
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    location /api/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

I tried every variation of config I could find using google-foo and couldn't get any to work.  If I curl the api from the CLI I get the expected json return.  So I think the problem is in the NGINX config.  Any help or suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: There's a typo on `proxy_pass http:127.0.0.1:8080;` <-- gotta be http://

Comment: Thanks, updated the question, still same problem on the server

Comment: Solved by figuring out that my CouchDB views were not working because of a dependency conflict

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for answering my own question...Figured out that CouchDB had a dependency conflict and was not serving views properly.  Figured that out by setting up an SSH tunnel and using the /_utils to try and modify and view the /views for my database.